# Webpack build file size is big also production mode not work

Tags: webpack-4

Whole problem is whne i set mode to development in webPack config !

Log looks like this:

```
  imgs/screen.png  231 bytes          [emitted]
          imgs/floor.png   1.74 KiB          [emitted]
      imgs/wallStock.jpg   77.1 KiB          [emitted]
   imgs/android-icon.png   16.4 KiB          [emitted]
  imgs/favicon-96x96.png   7.06 KiB          [emitted]
     /styles/favicon.ico   1.12 KiB          [emitted]
     imgs/gcheckmark.png  768 bytes          [emitted]
     imgs/microphone.png  545 bytes          [emitted]
         imgs/target.png   25.4 KiB          [emitted]
    imgs/share-files.png  774 bytes          [emitted]
        imgs/warning.png    1.3 KiB          [emitted]
         imgs/webcam.png  398 bytes          [emitted]
            visualjs2.js   1.84 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
                app.html   2.52 KiB          [emitted]
/templates/register.html    1.1 KiB          [emitted]
   /templates/login.html   1.06 KiB          [emitted]
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./src/style/styles.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/style/styles.css 9.28 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/app-icon.ts] 641 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/app.ts] 524 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/examples/platformer/platformer.ts] 839 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/examples/platformer/scripts/level1/level1.ts] 5.69 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/icon/permission/webcam.png] 61 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/libs/class/browser.ts] 5.02 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/libs/class/networking/network.ts] 24.9 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/libs/class/view-port.ts] 2.32 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/libs/class/visual-render.ts] 4.15 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/libs/client-config.ts] 2.15 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/libs/ioc.ts] 1.37 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/libs/multiplatform/global-event.ts] 1.48 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/libs/starter.ts] 4.71 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/style/styles.css] 1.06 KiB {main} [built]
```

**Webpack config :**

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const TypedocWebpackPlugin = require('typedoc-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    watch: true,
    entry: "./src/app.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "visualjs2.js",
        path: __dirname + "/build"
    },

    devtool: "inline-source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/, loader: "file-loader", options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: "./imgs"
                }
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.(ico)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: '/styles'
                    }
                }
            },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // Make sure that the plugin is after any plugins that add images
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build'], { /*exclude:  ['index.html']*/ }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'app.html',
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: '/templates/register.html',
            template: 'src/html-components/register.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: '/templates/login.html',
            template: 'src/html-components/login.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ],
    /*
    new TypedocWebpackPlugin({
        out: './api-doc',
        module: 'amd',
        target: 'es5',
        exclude: '** /node_modules / ** / *.* ',
        experimentalDecorators: true,
        excludeExternals: true,
        name: 'sn-theme',
        mode: 'file',
        theme: './sn-theme/',
        includeDeclarations: false,
        ignoreCompilerErrors: true,
    })
    */
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'async',
            minSize: 30000,
            maxSize: 0,
            minChunks: 2,
            maxAsyncRequests: 5,
            maxInitialRequests: 3,
            automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
            name: true,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    priority: -10
                },
                default: {
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Optimisation work's.Any way only tsconfig.json-> mode : "commonjs" works.

Why **visualjs2.js 1.84 MiB main** file is so big !
Any suggestion?

mode : production results :

> WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the
>   recommended size limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
>   Assets:   visualjs2.js (1.52 MiB)
>
> WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined
>   asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact
>   web performance. Entrypoints:   main (1.52 MiB)
>         visualjs2.js
>
> WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: You can limit the size
>   of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some
>   parts of your application. For more info visit
>   https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Error after **setup webpack.config mode: "production"**
 (not important to much, for this problem is on webpack area):

> visualjs2.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWidth' of
>   undefined
>       at new e (visualjs2.js:1)
>       at e.singlton (visualjs2.js:1)
>       at new e (visualjs2.js:1)
>       at Object. (visualjs2.js:1)
>       at Object. (visualjs2.js:1)
>       at n (visualjs2.js:1)
>       at visualjs2.js:1
>       at visualjs2.js:1

This is my package (dependency) :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/matter-js": "^0.10.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "matter-attractors": "^0.1.6",
    "matter-js": "^0.14.1",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "tsconfig": "^7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "websocket": "^1.0.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.13.0",
    "typedoc-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
```

Comment: While it depends on what you are all importing, `development` mode and `inline-source-map` can cause larger bundle sizes. Have you tried using `production` mode and either no source map or regular ones for testing?

Comment: Changing the source map should not cause errors in the code. [Webpack devtool options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) for reference. Also not too sure how without inline-source-map you lose ~1.5MB, might be something with the mapping.

Comment: With devtool: "source-map" i got   visualjs2.js 715 KiB [emitted] & visualjs2.js.map  876 KiB , This works in browser. I got 250kb~ if i remove devTool !

Comment: Source maps help you with debugging to see where errors occurred in the original files. There is not any reason why changing the devtool option would cause new errors in your code.

Comment: I updated Q , in new bug build my lib is  <visualjs2.js 229 KiB>  nice but still not working! I need to test production cases ... https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/